# Have link appear only if href file exists

Tags: javascript, html

I have a generic index.html file that has an unordered list of links. I only want the links to be visible if the file that they link to exists.

```
    <ul>
    <li><a class="button" href="text-1.htm">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="text-2.htm">Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="text-3.htm">Text 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Is this possible with JavaScript, or would I have to use PHP?

Comment: It’s possible with JavaScript in various ways. Either you keep a list of valid links or you send server requests and check the response.

Comment: If you want to do this on the client side, you would need to run some sort of check for the `HTTP Status: 200` (valid, exists, is working properly), which would need to be done via javascript. It may be easier (and less of a network load) to do the check via some server-side PHP which would simply check for the presence of a local file via `file_exists()`.

Comment: ew. you're using `.htm` as the file extension. ew. hashtag-1995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally be using PHP for this, but that's just my opinion, if someone else has a better JS solution, use that instead!

Here is the PHP version I would use:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul>';
    $files = ['text-1.htm', 'text-2.htm', 'text-3.htm'];
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $file_clean = explode('.', $file);
            $file_clean = str_replace('-', ' ', $file_clean[0]);
            $file_clean = ucfirst($file_clean);
            echo '<li><a class="button" href="' . $file . '">' . $file_clean . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Try that, see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible as long as the files are all on the same protocol, domain and port as the page being viewed.

You could for instance do an ajax request to see if each file can be gotten

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (function(button, http) {
        http.open('HEAD', button.href);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState != this.DONE || this.status != 200) {
                button.style.display = 'none';
            }
        };
        http.send();
    }(buttons[i], new XMLHttpRequest()))
}
```

Generally though, you'd want to manually make sure that the links actually do exists, rather than checking it clientside.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Ashley is close, but if the link refers to a huge file ajax will try to download the entire file before responding.  Here's an ajax solution where just the header is requested for each link on the page, then shows it if it's a valid link:

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  $.ajax({
    context: this,
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(data) {
      $(this).closest("li").css('display','list-item');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log($(this).attr('href') + ' Does not appear to exist');
    },
  })
});
```

```css
li{
display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Cnn.svg/2000px-Cnn.svg.png">CNN Logo</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/2000pxa-Cnn.svg.png">Nonsense Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="button" href="text-3.htm">Text 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: FWIW, I can think of a use case where it'd be useful to know if the link is valid from the user's machine.  Say they're behind a firewall or some sort of corporate URL filter.  What the server can access may not be the same as the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make a javascript observer testing if the file exists and then use show and hide or jquery attr to display your href or hide em

Comment: Please provide an example of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this below using Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'website.com/text-1.html',
  success: function(data){
    $('.mySelector').addClass(); //do something like add a class to show link
  },
  error: function(data){
   console.log('Does not appear to exist');
  },
})
```